How to prevent Safari 18 from forcing HSTS policy for subdomains for development purposes?
I have a variety of sites under development staged using subdomains of a single domain (e.g., this.example.com, that.example.com, etc.).  Some implement SSL; some don't. This is fine – they're all works in progress not accessible outside my LAN.
The problem is that Safari remembers its HSTS policy for an entire domain, not per subdomain.  Once it loads https://this.example.com, it refuses not only to load http://thissub.example.com, but also http://that.example.com.  Removing the local data for the parent domain under “Safari > Settings > Privacy > Manage Website Data” works until various changes between http and https are remembered, at which point it once against rejects all http connections.
The constant nannying means it's not feasible to analyze the developing sites using Safari, which is particularly annoying since that's the target browser for all of them.  Older suggestions (e.g., delete ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist) aren't applicable to  Safari 18. Is there some way to force it to stop mothering me?

Is this behavior different than other browsers? If it is not different then I'm not sure you can resolve this issue since it's behaving to the spec. You would need to disable HSTS during development.

If the main domain includes the includeSubDomains directive in its HSTS header, like the following, Safari will apply this to all subdomains. This is following the spec.
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
Don't serve the header with this directive if you wish for subdomains to not be forced to HTTPS.
